# How to study $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^x}{e^x+\sqrt{e^x}}$

Tags: integration

I need to study the convergence of $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^x}{e^x+\sqrt{e^x}}$, but I don't understand where to begin. I want to compaire it somehow to $\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}}$ to prove it convergent or divergent somehow (I do believe it is convergent judging by the graph of the function)

Could you please help me with a hint where do I begin?

Comment: Note that by setting $t=e^{x/2}$ you also get an easy anti-derivative on $[0,A]$, just need to study the limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the the fact that $\frac {e^{x}} {e^{x}+e^{x/2}} \geq \frac1  2 $ for all $x >0$.

Comment: Then I just simply say, that since $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2}\,dx=\infty$, so is the integral in the question?

Comment: @Dknot Yes, that is a complete proof.

Comment: I wonder if it could work saying that $\frac{1}{2}$ is $\frac{1}{2x^0}$. I suppose not, since Riemann integral diverges for $\alpha\leq1$ on the interval of $\{1,+\infty\}$ and we study the integral in question on $\{0,+\infty\}$